# Как в CSS сделать треугольник с тенью?

Tags: css

Вопрос в заголовке. Пробовал наложить тень как и на `:before` так и на обычную картинку в svg, всегда наложение тени происходит на прямоугольную область. Не уж то единственный способ размещение картинки уже с нарисованной тенью?

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 40px;
}

.menu {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
              0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
              0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.menu:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: 30px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 40px;
}

.menu {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
              0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
              0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.menu:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: 30px;
  background: white;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(15px) translateY(15px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #909090;
}
.menu .content{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Суть примерно следующая - есть сам блок, квадрат - он отбрасывает тень. Поверх него элемент after - он тоже квадрат, но повернут на 45 градусов, смещен так чтоб виднелся только уголок (с помощью transform) и отбрасывает тень. Но он будет отбрасывать тень и на сам блок, а если сделать блок поверх - то блок будет отбрасывать тень на уголок. Поэтому в блоке меню делаем еще один блок - собсно, где будет всё содержимое - указываем ему position, указываем z-index чтоб он был поверх элемента after и уже далее паддинги и все остальное задаем ему.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно использовать CSS-фигуры.

Директива shape-outside: url(image.png) говорит браузеру, чтобы он извлёк очертания фигуры из изображения.

Свойство shape-image-threshold задаёт минимальный уровень прозрачности, при котором пикселы будут участвовать в формировании фигуры. Значение этого свойства может изменяться в диапазоне от 0.0 (полностью прозрачный) до 1.0 (полностью непрозрачный).

[Ссылка на полное описание](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_2099.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Но с поддержкой, по-видимому, всё очень плохо.